# UICollection View Async Images loading + reloading

Tags: ios, json, swift, asynchronous, loading

I've the following problem:

I have a view controller with UICollection View, textual data (name, url of image) comes from json using swiftyJSON, but all the images are downloaded asynchronically in such way:

`func loadImageForCell(url: String, imageView: UIImageView){

```
    let downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("io.test.downloadimage", nil)

    dispatch_async(downloadQueue){

        var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!)

        var image: UIImage?

        if (data != nil){

            image = UIImage(data: data!)!

        }



        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

            imageView.image = image


        }


    }


}
```

`

I also have such requirement that by choosing a value in picker, another json request must be sent and collection view should be updated (reloaded) accordingly to the received information.

When I add collectionView.reloadData(), it works for textual data, but images are mixing. All cells contain wrong images.

This function is executed when item in picker is chosen:

```
func updateLabel(){



    var sizeComponent = PickerComponent.size.rawValue

    var chosenCategory = pickerData[sizeComponent][myPicker.selectedRowInComponent(sizeComponent)]
  [myPicker.selectedRowInComponent(toppingComponent)]
    CategoryLabel.setTitle(chosenCategory, forState: .Normal)

    ArrayOfDescSmall = []
    ArrayOfURLs = []

    let url = NSURL(string: "***")
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

    var hoge = JSON(data: data!)

    let sampleJson = hoge.array

        if(sampleJson == nil){

            TotalNumber = 0

        } else{

    TotalNumber = sampleJson!.count   

        }

   for(var i = 0; i < TotalNumber; i++){

        ArrayOfDescSmall.append(hoge[i]["name"].string!)
        ArrayOfURLs.append(hoge[i]["imageUrl"].string!)
    }

        CollectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -60), animated:true)
    }



}
```

How to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your cells display wrong images is because cells are reused in the collection view, and looks like you do not cancel your data request when cells are reused. It is easy to fix though.
Add two properties to your custom cell class:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSURSessionDataTask *imageDataTask;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSURL *imageUrl;
```

Add a custom setter for the url, something like this:

```
- (void)setImageUrl:(NSURL *)imageUrl {
  _imageUrl = imageUrl;
  self.imageDataTask = 'new nsurlsessiondatatask for your image, 
        with a completion handler where you convert data into an image, 
        and set image to the imageView on the main thread'
  [self.imageDataTask resume];
}
```

Implement "prepareForReuse" method, and cancel your data task there, like this:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
  [super prepareForReuse];
  [self.imageDataTask cancel];
}
```

Now when you set a new imageUrl to your cell it will automatically start the download, and then it will display the image when the download completes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! But could you tell me how to perform that in Swift?

Comment: And one more thing: is that necessary to separate cells into its own file? I mean I have only one function describing cells behaviour: cellForItemAtIndexPath . And everything connected to cells is written there.